# Files + Form Data values to WebAPI controller via jQuery using memory only?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

### The Components

- A form with some values on an asp.net web form
- A file input (standard HTML5, not asp:File or anything like that)
- The bluimp jQuery file uploader which I understand is pretty great for this sort of thing but have never used
- An MVC4 WebAPI controller
- A knockoutJS viewmodel in the web form's JavaScript (shouldn't matter here but worth mentioning).

### The Goal

Basically, I have tiny Excel sheets that I'm uploading to validate, process, turn into business objects, and return as JSON items.

I'd like the following to happen:

- User types in some data to the form, etc.
- User adds a file to the form.
- The file is automatically uploaded (using bluimp control) to the MVC controller along with a form field value that contains text.

Next, on the controller,

- the text field passed in is sanitized/validated.
- the file is processed into memory

  - (these are truly tiny and there aren't many of them so I'm thinking we shouldn't need to go to the file system?)
- The file is then processed using a `FileProcessor` that uses the stream and is instantiated using the text field.

### The Problem

I don't understand these components well enough yet to understand if I'm making a simple mistake aor a complex one.

### What I Have so Far

NOTE: Was trying this with a button to explicitly click to send the file, though in the future I'd like to do it automatically.

**The form to submit the file:**

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" action="/api/InvoiceDetailsFile/PostForProcessing" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type ="hidden" name="clientSiteId" id="clientSiteId" value="3"/>
        <input type="file" id="inpFile" required="required"/>
<input type ="button" id="btnSendFile" title="Send File" value="Send File"/>

</form>
```

**The JavaScript for the Upload (this is likely very wrong):**

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            'use strict';

            var btnSendFile = $("#btnSendFile");
            var frmFileUpload = $("#fileUploadForm");

            btnSendFile.click(function () {
                console.log('send button clicked');
                frmFileUpload.fileupload("send");
            });
 });
```

**The WebAPI Controller to handle the upload (this is likely very wrong):**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<List<IInvoiceDetailItem>> PostForProcessing(int clientSiteId)
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var results = new List<IInvoiceDetailItem>();

        var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    // can I only expect 1 item here?
                    foreach (var item in streamProvider.Contents)
                    {
                        // if it's an Excel Sheet
                        if (item.IsMimeMultipartContent("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
                        {
                            try {
                                var workbook = new XLWorkbook(item.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

                                // clientSiteId here comes from form value (via constructor?), ContextUser comes from a BaseApi.
                                var processor =
                                    new InvoiceProcessorFactory(clientSiteId, ContextUser) 
                                        .GetInvoiceProcessorInstance();
                                 results = processor.ProcessInvoice(workbook).ToList();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                throw new HttpException(Convert.ToInt32(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError), "Well, this is a bummer. The invoice processor failed. Please see the inner exception.", ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return results;
                });
        return task;
    }
```

I'll continue to update the code samples as I progress but I wanted to get it out there sooner than later since I know I'll be struggling with it.

Comment: just a small correction..you seem to be using a MVC `Post` attribute on a Web API action...

Comment: Oops! Fixed, thanks -- will update here too.

Comment: I see some issues with your server side code...i believe you do not have an end-to-end flow ready yet for you to easily test..right? if yes, then i would suggest to try testing with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to uploading multipart form data content...The `System.Net.Http` library has a content called `MultipartFormDataContent` through which you can simulate a request how a browser would do..this way you can figure out if your server code is good or not...